# .NET Core not showing in target framework dropdown for visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have installed .NET core 3.1 and verified i can run .NET core 3.1 apps on my machine however when i go to create a new project the dropdown for target frameworks only allows .NET 6.0. I am using visual studio 2022. I am using visual studio 2019 on my laptop and i can add .NET core projects just fine.

[image]

Has anyone ran into this?

Comment: In order to **run** a .NET Core 3.1 app, you need the .NET Core 3.1 runtime - which you obviously have, if you can run the app. But for VS 2022 to be able to use .NET Core 3.1 as a targetting platform, you need the .NET Core 3.1 **SDK** - not just the runtime......

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the app in either 5 or 6. Then in the Application properties change the Target Framework to .Net 3.1.

[image: Change in Visual Studio after Project Creation]

Long term support is limited for anything before .Net 5, so they are not making it an option on new projects and directing to the newer versions.

Answer (score 21):

- Open Visual studio installer from start menu
- Select Modify from Visual Studio that you want to add
- in individual components select .net core or framework that you want to add to your visual studio version

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Simply updating VS fixed the problem for me

Comment: Yes, simply updating the VS to the latest worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using VS2022 and was facing the same issue. I installed the .NET SDK 3.1.416 from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1) and restarted the VS. I am now able to create project with .NET core 3.1 target framework.

[image: Target framework 3.1 - VS2022]