# Visual Studio isn't picking up any installed frameworks

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I just updated my Visual Studio Community 2022 (17.4.3) and since then none of my projects are building and they're all throwing errors and aren't picking up any installed frameworks, I've triple checked that they're all still installed (they're still showing as options when I go to create a new project), restarted my PC several times, repaired my Visual Studio installation but still nothing, this applies to newly created projects as well as existing ones.

Does anyone know of any fixes for this? or is this something I should take up with Microsoft?

Screenshots of the error message & missing frameworks below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core not showing in target framework dropdown for visual studio 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327725/net-core-not-showing-in-target-framework-dropdown-for-visual-studio-2022)

Comment: @MDZand No because all the installed frameworks are still showing up when I create a new project

Answer (score 0):

Only fix I've been able to come up with as of yet was to roll back to a version that works, currently 17.3.6