# Downgrade .NET 6 API to .NET Core 3

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0, csproj, .net-core-3.0

I cannot create a .NET Core 3 application using Visual Studio 2022. It is only showing .NET 6 and 7.

I want to publish this API on IIS server, which does not support .NET 6.

I tried to change the project version from in the properties or in the `csproj` file, but it causes errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core not showing in target framework dropdown for visual studio 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327725/net-core-not-showing-in-target-framework-dropdown-for-visual-studio-2022)

Comment: Don't run a .NET 3 application on IIS.
Make the upgrade to .NET 6 work.
There are too many security risks in running a web server that will likely have unpatched, but documented, vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

**@Tony B said .net core 3.1 has security concerns be mindful of that. But If you really want to downgrade your project, Follow these steps :**

**1. Open the Visual Studio installer.**
[image]
**2. Select modify in the VS2022 instance.**
[image]
**3. Go to the Individual Component tab.**
[image]

**4. Select .net core 3.1(LTS) and click install**
[image]

**After the above installation is done Optionally - proceed with machine restart.**

**Then open your project in visual studio 2022.**

**1. Goto Application properties and select target framework as .net core 3.1**

[image]